# Declare class variable in different scene

Tags: swift, class

I'm pretty new to Swift. I'm creating an application that allows a user to create registration forms. I have two files/scenes, FirstViewController, and SecondViewController. The SecondViewController allows the user to create a question. The FirstViewController will display all the created questions in a UITableView. In my SecondViewController I have a class called Question which basically helps me create a question, it is shown below for context.

```
class Question {
    var Label: String
    var required: Int

    // create question
    init (Label: String, required: Int) {
        self.Label = Label
        self.required = required
    }

}

class textInput: Question {
    var placeHolder: String

    init (placeHolder: String, Label: String, required: Int) {
        self.placeHolder = placeHolder
        super.init(Label: Label, required: required)
    }
}

class multiChoice: Question {
    var answers: [String]

    init(answers: [String], Label: String, required: Int) {
        self.answers = answers
        super.init(Label: Label, required: required)
    }

}
```

In the FirstViewController I need to create an array of that type to keep a running list of all the questions in the UITableView...

```
var formQuestions: [Question]
```

Obviously the FirstViewController does not have access to this custom object type. My question is how do I make it so that it does? I could copy and paste the entire class over to my FirstViewController but that would be terrible programming...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just put each class in a separate file, then they'll be available from anywhere in your project.

Comment: Can you elaborate? So what you are saying is copy the Question class to FirstViewController.swift?

Comment: No, just add a file called, for instance, "Question.swift" to your project and put the Question class in there, instead of in either of the files for your view controller classes. Then you can make new `Question` instances from anywhere in your project.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. This will sound like a pretty nooby question, but how do I create a new instance of the Question class?

Comment: Just like you have: `var question: Question`, or if you want an array of them, `var formQuestions: [Question]` exactly like you did. To initialize it at the same time, just go `var question = Question()`, or `var formQuestions: [Question] = []`

Comment: I really appreciate the help! Seems to be working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FirstViewController` doesn't have access to the `Question` class and its subclasses because they are all declared in `SecondViewController`. This means they are local to `SecondViewController` and nowhere else can access it. What you need to do is to make the question class *global*.

So at the moment your classes are like: (contents omitted)

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    class Question {
    }

    class TextInputQuestion: Question {
    }

    class MultiChoiceQuestion: Question {
    }
}
```

You should move them out of the `SecondViewController`:

```
class SecondViewController {
}

class Question {
}

class TextInputQuestion: Question {
}

class MultiChoiceQuestion: Question {
}
```

Oh by the way, I renamed your class names! You should always use PascalCase for classes and I think adding the word `Question` would be more descriptive of what they are.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it earlier but did not update that it was fixed. I'll give you points for effort:)

Comment: What is not an issue? When you move the classes to a separate file, essentially you are just moving the classes _out of_ the `SecondViewController` and thus they become accessible everywhere in your project, including `FirstViewController`. @Malexc

Comment: Yes. I amended my response realizing I was on a different stackoverflow question. I apologize.